# Oauth 2.0 client secret on GitHub [CLI app]

Tags: github, oauth-2.0, command-line-interface, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I'm building a CLI app that uses *Google Calendar API*, which requires the `client_secret.json` generated in the *Google Dev Console*. I want to make the app Open-Source on Github, and so it is to my understanding that I have to put `client_secret.json` in the repo so people can run the app on their terminal without having to start again the process of registering on the *Google Dev Console*.

Is it an issue? I store nothing about the users, I just create events programmatically in the user's calendar.

Comment: While you could do as you suggest, bear in mind quotas and potential abuse. VonC's approach is more complex for the end user, but is the safest option. As always you're balancing security vs convenience.

Comment: Yep, exactly what I thought

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar open-source projects involving a Calendar have a different approach.
See for instance "[`arvind-iyer/CourseSchedulerHKUST`](https://github.com/arvind-iyer/CourseSchedulerHKUST)":

> Run `quickstart.py` with Python 2.7 after installing all the dependencies with the command `pip install -r requirements.txt`.
> **Create a google dev app and obtain client secrets and store as client_secret.json in the directory before running `quickstart.py`**

In other words, each user needs to come up with his/her own client secrets, instead of you having to store and share yours.

Comment: Thanks, that's spot on